# Is it possible to cache pointers to Java arrays / objects?

Tags: android, pointers, caching, java-native-interface

I have a Java class:

```
public class JavaClass {

    private static int id;
    private static float[] array;

    public JavaClass() {
        this.id = 0;
        this.array = new float[10];    
    }

    public native void initialiseCached();
    public native void longManipulation();
}
```

I instantiate it in Java and want to use `longManipulation()` which operates on member static arrays (only shown one here), is it possible to cache a pointer to these fields so I can avoid getting a fresh pointer every time I call `longManipulation()`? I'm trying to avoid too many calls through the interface as per the [IBM best practice](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jni/).

So my JNI code would be something like:

```
static jclass JC_class;
static jint* ptr_id;
static jfloat* ptr_array;

Java_my_package_name_initialiseCached(JNIEnv* env, jobject instance) {

    JC_class = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(env->FindClass("my/package/name/JavaClass"));

    // Get pointer to id field and store in static variable which should
    // remain while library is loaded.
    ptr_id = (jint*)env->GetStaticObjectField(JC_class,
                                      env->GetStaticFieldID(JC_class, "id", "I"));

    // Get pointer to head of array and store
    ptr_id = env->GetFloatArrayElements(
            (jint*)env->GetStaticObjectField(
                JC_class, env->GetStaticFieldID(JC_class, "array", "[F")
            )
        );
}

// Then called at some later time //
Java_my_package_name_longManipulation(JNIEnv* env, jobject instance) {

// Use pointer without interfacing with Java again
ptr_array[0] = ...

}
```

[A blog post](https://thinkingandcomputing.com/posts/persisting-java-objects-across-jni-calls.html) I read seems to suggest that this can be done but I find JNI very temperamental due to my limit knowledge and need some advice. The alternative is to get a fresh pointer every time I call `longManipulation()` by passing the fields of `JavaClass` in as arguments and getting the pointer with `GetFloatArrayElements()` or by caching the `FieldID` and using `GetStaticObjectField()` followed by the former which all sounds rather expensive. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: It's fine to cache a `jmethodID` / `jfieldID`. For an object/class reference, such as a `jclass` or a `jfloatArray` you would have to obtain a global reference with `NewGlobalRef` if you want to cache that reference. Make sure that you delete that global reference when you no longer need it. And of course, check for bad return values and exceptions after every JNI call.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for the reply. Would it then be possible to get a persistent pointer to an array field like this: `ptr_id = env->NewGlobalRef( env->GetFloatArrayElements(
            (jint*)env->GetStaticObjectField(
                JC_class, env->GetStaticFieldID(JC_class, "array", "[F")
            )
        ) );`?

Comment: `NewGlobalRef` requires a `jobject` whereas `GetFloatArrayElements` is usually cast to pointer of `jxxxx` where `xxxx` is a primitive type. I was hoping for it to return a handle to the Java side array which I would put in the reference.